# Using if is_page() Wordpress conditional statement

Tags: wordpress, tags, conditional-statements, if-statement

I'm trying to have different pictures on every one of my pages built on wordpress.

So I have the following in my index.php file, archive.php file, page.php file, etc:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo $toppic; ?>" alt="page1" id="mainPageImg" />
```

Now, in my page.php file, I have the following:

```
<?php
    // TOP PICTURE DEFINITIONS
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $toppic == 'page1.png';
    }
    if ( is_page('articles') ) {
        $toppic == 'page2.png';
    }
?>
```

How come this does not work? I tried it with one equal (=) sign...

EDIT: If I define $toppic at the top, for example, in the index.php file as follows:

```
<?php $toppic = 'page1.png'; ?>
```

Then it works. So therefore, it must be something that has to do with the conditional if is_page/is_home statements. Any ideas?

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer.

This is what needs to be done. For the articles (blog) page, at the top section you need to place the following:

```
<?php // TOP PICTURE DEFINITION FOR ARTICLES PAGE
        if ( is_home() ) {
            $toppic = 'page1.png';
        }
?>
```

Then, in your page.php file, you can control the picture at the top for all other pages (except 404, where you'd need to put a is_404() in your 404.php. So this is what it looks like:

```
<?php
    // TOP PICTURE DEFINITIONS
    if ( is_page('english') ) {
        $toppic = 'page1.png';
    }
    if ( is_page('aboutus') ) {
        $toppic = 'page1.png';
    }
    if ( is_page('newspaper') ) {
        $toppic = 'page1.png';
    }
    else {
        $toppic = 'page1.png';
    }
?>
```

And finally, in order to implement this, use the following HTML/php syntax:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo $toppic ?>" alt="page1" id="mainPageImg" />
```

That's all. Phew. Finally got it to work :) Had to do it for a client, too!

Comment: I'm not getting what the solution was, is your "articles" page also your home page?

Comment: The articles page is not my home page. I have set a 'static' front page. However, Wordpress function is_home() returns 'true' for the blog page (aka my articles page). That's why you have to place is_home() on the index.php file, is_404() on the 404.php file, and is_page() in the page.php file. Hope that helped

Comment: Ok, I thought 'articles' was one of your static pages not your blog page. Yes `is_home()` is the page which is your main blog page and `is_front_page()` is your front page.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to show posts on more than one page?

Answer (score 1):

The slug for your Articles page has to be defined as `articles`. This is set in the edit page interface, see [these directions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Changing_the_URL_.28or_.22Slug.22.29_of_Your_Pages).

Comment: Yeah true. I'll look into that

Comment: I just checked it, the slug is set for articles...I should mention that this is a child page of a parent page. Should that matter?

Comment: All of the other pages now work except the blog (articles) page

Comment: I even tried to do is_page('53') where '53' is the ID of the articles (blog) page. How-come this doesn't work but all others do!$@!$